# Incrementing a date in python

Tags: python, pandas, date

In pandas I have a variable defined as

```
start_date = date (2020,7,1)
```

How do I update it to be the next day? I have a dataframe and I am filtering on individual days but I want to iterate through a full time range. I suppose I could have a for loop like so

```
for x < 10:
    start_date = date (2020,7,x)
    x +=1
```

But is there another way? I couldn't find any other stack exchange questions for python dates.

Comment: Is `date` a `datetime.date`?  If so, you can use `datetime.timedelta` to add a day to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `date` is the regular python one you can add a day as follows:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

start_date = date(2020, 7, 1)
next_date = start_date + timedelta(days=1)
```